# TimescaleDB - Counters

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series, counter, timescaledb

My goal is to query the delta of a counter metric over time using a continuous aggreate from TimescaleDB.

I'm following the example from [Running a counter aggregate query with a continuous aggregate](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/hyperfunctions/counter-aggregation/counter-aggs/#run-a-counter-aggregate-query-with-a-continuous-aggregate)

I created the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE example (
    measure_id      BIGINT,
    ts              TIMESTAMPTZ ,
    val             DOUBLE PRECISION,
    PRIMARY KEY (measure_id, ts)
);
```

Inserted some values for testing:

```sql
INSERT INTO example VALUES 
    (1, '2022-05-07 10:00', 0),
    (1, '2022-05-07 10:05', 5),
    (1, '2022-05-07 10:10', 10),
    (1, '2022-05-07 10:15', 15),
    (1, '2022-05-07 10:20', 20),
    (1, '2022-05-07 10:25', 25);
```

And then run the query that puts this data into time buckets and uses the *delta* accessor function to calculate the difference of the measurements over time:

```sql
SELECT measure_id,
    time_bucket('15 min'::interval, ts) as bucket,
    delta(counter_agg(ts, val, toolkit_experimental.time_bucket_range('15 min'::interval, ts)))
FROM example
GROUP BY measure_id, time_bucket('15 min'::interval, ts);
```

But the results don't match my expections:

| measure_id | bucket | delta |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-05-07 10:00:00+01 | 10 |
| 1 | 2022-05-07 10:15:00+01 | 10 |

The delta accessor works correctly as it substracts the last value of each time bucket from the first

> 10 - 0 = **10** 
> and
> 25 - 15 = **10**

but the overall delta is not correct: the metric grew from 0 to 25 which is equal to **25** and not 10 + 10 which is only **20**.

How can I get the "proper" delta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from @greenweeds I worked out this solution which seems to

- account for counter resets and
- ignore the initial counter value (I just want differences over time and the first value would be treated as such a difference although it is not)

Hope this helps others as well. My query:

```sql
SELECT
    measure_id,
    time_bucket('15 min', ts) AS bucket,
    SUM(diff_val) AS delta
FROM(
    SELECT 
        ts, 
        measure_id,
        -- Use 0 on counter resets
        CASE WHEN diff_val >= 0 THEN diff_val
        ELSE 0
        END AS diff_val
    FROM (
        SELECT
            ts,
            measure_id,
            -- Calculate the change in the counter from current to last value
            val - LAG(val,1,0) OVER (
                ORDER BY ts
            ) AS diff_val
        FROM example
        ORDER BY 1,2
    ) AS base
    -- Remove the first (oldest) data rows - they containt the initial counter values which we ignore as they could be very high and make the final chart unusable
    WHERE ts != (SELECT ts FROM example LIMIT 1)
) AS final
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2
```

I tested this against a more complex data set:

```sql
INSERT INTO example VALUES 
    (1, '2022-05-07 10:00', 1000),
    (1, '2022-05-07 10:05', 1005),
    (1, '2022-05-07 10:10', 1010),
    (1, '2022-05-07 10:12', 0),
    (1, '2022-05-07 10:15', 5),
    (1, '2022-05-07 10:20', 10),
    (1, '2022-05-07 10:31', 15);
```

And the result is what I expected:

```
| measure_id | bucket                 | delta |
|------------|------------------------|-------|
| 1          | 2022-05-07 10:00:00+01 |10     |
| 1          | 2022-05-07 10:15:00+01 |10     |
| 1          | 2022-05-07 10:30:00+01 |5      |
```

Answer (score 2):

it looks as though you may have encountered a known issue. Although it's not ideal for Stack Overflow there are some very long conversations at the two links I'll post at the end of this answer. They're too detailed to post here accurately. However, I will post an explanation of the source of the problem, and a workaround is currently in development (July 2022). You can find out more about the workaround at the second link.

> Unfortunately, these aggregates have a major weakness when data is grouped by time range, which is a very common use case. When Postgres groups data, each point is uniquely assigned to one group, and a function called on that group has no visibility into adjacent groups. This breaks our ability to do pairwise computations at the boundaries between groups.
>
> We should be able to work around this using our pipeline functionality, but it will take a significant effort to design and mature a robust solution based around this (and this might not even be viable for mega-scale workloads). Fortunately Postgres does have a mechanism for this problem that we can leverage for a more immediate workaround, and that is window functions.

1. https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-toolkit/issues/358
2. https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-toolkit/issues/440

*Transparency: I work for Timescale*

Comment: Thanks! Using your links I think I found a working solution. Will post it as an answer. Waiting for the proper implementation of the timescaledb team :)

Comment: Although the solution I mentioned in my answer below seems to work, it won't allow me to create a continuous aggregate (MATERIALIZED VIEW). This is crucial for me as I will have millions of rows in that raw hypertable and I need to bucket it into one-hour buckets to make the corresponding Grafana dashboard load fast. Error message is not particularly helpful: **invalid continuous aggregate query**

Comment: Hi Kurt it would be worth upvoting on the issues in GitHub (thumbs up is enough) to add your "voice" to the need for a workaround. I'll also check to see if we can see the reason for that error message.

Comment: I did give a thumbs up to this one: https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-toolkit/issues/440